# How to filter label_values in Loki?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to create a query variable in grafana using Loki that returns all the possible label values of the label **baz** such that they only include label values that exist where the label **foo** equals **"bar"**.
Looking at the docs, I came up with the following query for the variable:

label_values(rate({foo=~"bar"}, baz)

However this returned all the possible baz label values and not only those that exist while foo="bar", basically the results are the same as:

label_values(baz)

What am I doing wrong? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching this, i've found an [open issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/25205) on grafana's github. At the time of writing its still in the backlog.